# actionserve/client in latest rosjava

Tags: rosjava

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,
I am still keen to know how can we make action client/server in latest rosjave version? does latest rosjava give some lib to make actionservers and clients? OR action client servers are totally removed from the rosjava??????

Thnaks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/42461/actionserve/client-in-latest-rosjava/) by [safzam](https://answers.ros.org/users/118/safzam/) on ROS Answers with karma: 111 on 2012-08-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Sorry, the answer has not changed. See http://answers.ros.org/question/37198/rosjava-actionlib/

---

Originally posted by [damonkohler](https://answers.ros.org/users/653/damonkohler/) with karma: 3838 on 2012-09-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0